# Captcha accepts both capital and small letters

Tags: asp.net, captcha

I have developed a captcha code verification . But it accepts both capital letters and small letters.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim());
        if (Captcha1.UserValidated)
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "Valid";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "InValid"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CAPTCHA is not case sensitive, specifically RECAPTCHA from Google, which by the looks of it, is what you are using.

Comment: It is not case sensitive. Which means it doesn't matter if you use a Capital or lowercase letter.

Comment: Is better to accept them both - let it as is.